# How do I console.log responses from the TikTok API?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, tiktok

I subscribed to the Tiktok API. I want to console.log the entire response, and results like stats.videoCount or stats.viewCount.

Partial code here:

```
fetch("https://api.promptapi.com/tiktok/hashtag/{planttrees}", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Which successfully returns the following JSON response.

```
"{
    'challengeInfo': {
        'challenge': {
            'id': '50923585',
            'title': 'planttrees',
            'desc': '',
            'profileThumb': '',
            'profileMedium': '',
            'profileLarger': '',
            'coverThumb': '',
            'coverMedium': '',
            'coverLarger': '',
            'isCommerce': false
        },
        'stats': {
            'videoCount': 1420,
            'viewCount': 4500000
        },
        'challengeAnnouncement': {
            'body': '',
            'title': ''
        }
    },
    'shareMeta': {
        'title': '#planttrees on TikTok',
        'desc': '4.0m views - Watch awesome short videos created with trending hashtag #planttrees'
    }
}
"

console.log(result)
console.log(response)
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
```

don't work. How can I log this response in the console?

Comment: Try `response.json()` instead of `response.text()`

Comment: response.json in the JS doesn't make the correct API call, and yields no response. The call is fine, I just need to know how to work with it when it comes into the console.

Answer (score 0):

you can put your console logs in the .then function of your API call.

```
fetch("https://api.promptapi.com/tiktok/hashtag/{planttrees}", requestOptions)
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(response.stats);
      console.log(response.stats.viewCount);
   }
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: Your code as it is misses a closing brace: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list". Adding the closing brace yields an [object Error]. I also want to learn how to work with the JSON data flexibly from the console.